KDE environment distro show black screen in my system
I fresh install Fedora with KDE in my desktop computer with ASRock motherboard and AMD Ryzen 5600G with iGPU and i made the bootable USB using balena etcher. When i update via terminal

sudo dnf update

After it done it suddenly show black screen with no cursor visible, after when i restart the system by click Alt + F2 to open terminal and enter my username and password then reboot, the black screen still persist.
Why is this happening? How do i fix it?

can you login to sddm/ the display manager, if so pick the x11 version instead of the wayland version or if using x11 switch to wayland
